# MongoDB & Spring Data - Searching for a user by firstname/lastname

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, criteria-api, database

I have the following collection:

```
User {
   firstname,
   lastname
}
```

I want to search for users by firstname and/or lastname (firstname/lastname/firstname+lastname).

What I have:

```
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
 criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where("firstname").regex(searchQuery),Criteria.where("lastname").regex(searchQuery));
```

The problem with the above is that I can either search by firstname OR lastname, but not both (e.g. ''John Smith'' is not possible while ''John'' or ''Smith'' is possible. 
This is happening because of the orOperator and I can not see any andOr or something similar.

So e.g. if I have "John Smith" inside my database, I can find him by querying either "John" , "Smith" , "John Smith" (just as in facebook for example)

Edit:

```
String queryx[] = searchQuery.split(" ");
for(String q : queryx) {
    criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where("firstname").regex(searchQuery),Criteria.where("lastname").regex(q));
}
```

Shows me the results, but it gives the following error inside my console:

```
  Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, you can't add a second '$or' expression specified as '$or : [ { "firstname" : { "$regex" : "john smith"}} , { "lastname" : { "$regex" : "smith"}}]'. Criteria already contains '$or : [ { "firstname" : { "$regex" : "john smith"}} , { "lastname" : { "$regex" : "john"}}]'.
```

Edit2:

```
String queryx[] = searchQuery.split(" ");
   ArrayList<Criteria> orOperators = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
for(String q : queryx) {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where("firstname").regex(searchQuery),Criteria.where("lastname").regex(q));
    orOperators.add(criteria);
}

Criteria [] orArray = orOperators.toArray(new Criteria[orOperators.size()]);
Criteria c = Criteria.where("firstname").regex(searchQuery);
c.orOperator(orArray);

Query query = new Query(c).limit(limit);
return mongoOperations.find(query, User.class);
```

Edit 3:

```
String queryx[] = searchQuery.split(" ");
ArrayList<Criteria> cr = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
for (String q : queryx) {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.orOperator(Criteria.where("firstname").regex(q),
            Criteria.where("lastname").regex(q));
    cr.add(criteria);
}

Query query = new Query();
for (Criteria cri : cr) {
    query.addCriteria(cri); //this is the problem
}

return mongoOperations.find(query, User.class);
```

Error:

```
 Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, you can't add a second 'null' criteria. Query already contains '{ "$or" : [ { "firstname" : { "$regex" : "john smith"}} , { "lastname" : { "$regex" : "john"}}]}'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To search for firstname AND lastname you can easily do this:

```
String queryx[] = searchQuery.split(" ");
ArrayList<Criteria> cr = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
for (String q : queryx) {
    Criteria fCriteria = Criteria.where("firstname").regex(q);
    cr.add(fCriteria);
    Criteria lCriteria = Criteria.where("lastname").regex(q);
    cr.add(lCriteria);
}
Criteria c = cr.remove(0);
Criteria [] orArray = orOperators.toArray(new Criteria[orOperators.size()]);
c.orOperator(orArray);
query.addCriteria(c); //this is the problem
return mongoOperations.find(query, User.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it does not work (I tried it). It looks when a firstname AND lastname match the searchQuery. 
I have editted my post for clarity.

Comment: Still it is not clear what you are searching for. Do you want to find that user when `searchQuery` is "John Smith"? if that is the case you have manually break the string into two parts and use only an orOperator.

Comment: Exactly. Just as in Facebook, whether you search for the firstname OR lastname OR firstname+lastname, it retrieves a user. I used th orOperator in the original post, but I don't know how to combine firstname+lastname.

Comment: So my proposal is split searchQuery in case it has spaces like in the updated post

Comment: thanks for your comment. I firstly received an array out of bounds error when I enter only 1 name (since there is not an queries[1] value). But even if I enter "John Smith", I receive the following error:
Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, you can't add a second '$or' expression specified as '$or : [ { "firsname" : { "$regex" : "john"} , "$and" : [ { "lastname" : { "$regex" : "smith"}}]}]'. Criteria already contains '$or : [ { "lastname" : { "$regex" : "john smith"}}]'.] with root cause

Comment: Updated the example; however the key is using a cascaded andOperator and orOperators

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not work. This time however, when I insert "John Smith", I do not see any result at all. Inserting only John however still gives me an index out of bound and no result.
Anyway, I appreciate your time and support. Isn't there really a simple way to combine 2 fields inside the database using Spring Data and just compare them against a query? Rather than splitting the query up?

Comment: Hi +pinturic, I updated my post with some code based on your idea. I can now actually search using firstname/lastname/firstname+lastname and see results! However, I see the following error in my console as the previous one, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Programmatically speaking you cannot call or operator more than once on the same criteria. Put them in an array and call it only once.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I updated the post again. However, now I can only search using the firstname. But I guess I am doing this process wrong?

Comment: Yes you are still using searchQueary instead of q in the for :D an please rate the answer if you like it.

Comment: I am unable to do that since q is outside the scope. 
I updated my answer (edit 3) and still see the results, but now get a null error. Is this fixable?
And of course I will accept your answer

Comment: You can try what I have added now in the test

Comment: It does not work. It appears to only work if firstname and lastname are equal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78324/discussion-between-pinturic-and-moody).

Answer (score 1):

I used it and succeeded

```
List<Criteria> userNameCriteriaList = Lists.newArrayList();

for (String key: keyWords) {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.orOperator(
         where(FIRST_NAME).regex(regex, "i"),
         where(LAST_NAME).regex(regex, "i")
    );
    userNameCriteriaList.add(criteria);
}

return new Criteria().andOperator(userNameCriteriaList.toArray(new Criteria[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using criteria, you can just put a `@TextIndexed` on `'firstname'` and `'lastname'` in your entity `'User'` and do this :

```
@Query("{ $text: { $search: ?0 } }")
List<User> searchUsers(String search);
```

It works for all this search queries :

- "john"
- "john doe"
- "doe john"
- "doe"